# summarise information reported by a named vector

Tags: r, character

I want to extrapolate the info reported by a character see below:

```
X<- c("BB", "BB", "CC", "CC", "CC", "EE", "EE")
names(X) <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
```

Character is below:

```
 X
       1    2    2    2    3    3    4 
    "BB" "BB" "CC" "CC" "CC" "EE" "EE"
```

`"CC"` in position 2 occurs twice, this info should be reported by the line `Time` Expected output:

```
  1    2    2   3    3    4    # Position
  1    1    2   1    1    1    # Times
"BB" "BB" "CC" "CC" "EE" "EE"  # Character
```

Tried:

```
table (names(X))
data.frame(X)
```

Comment: That's actually the point the CC "missing info" is included in the Time line

Comment: Why did you group the first two `CC` together?

Comment: He wants to count unique combinations of the characters and the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use group by operation on the `names` of 'X' with the values of 'X' and get the frequency

```
library(data.table)
data.table(X, nm = names(X))[, .N, .(X, nm)]
#    X nm N
#1: BB  1 1
#2: BB  2 1
#3: CC  2 2
#4: CC  3 1
#5: EE  3 1
#6: EE  4 1
```

---

Or similar option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(X, nm = names(X)) %>%
            count(X, nm)
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(n = rep(1, length(X))) ~ X + names(X), FUN = sum)
```